# RavenDb paging with session.load

Tags: ravendb

I am running a batch job that selects a batch of 100 documents, and then grabs all of the documents linked to it - possibly upto 25 for each.

I do the "join" using the ids from the first batch. So potentially I am calling session.load with 25 * 100 ids. I tried to implement paging, but it does not look possible using the load method which returns an array.

What is the best practice here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice is to use the .Include method rather than do what you are describing.  You can read more in [the documentation](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/querying/handling-document-relationships).

If you want to post some code of what you are doing now, I can provide a more detailed response.